# Local variable list defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

Tags: lambda, java-8

I have a method where am calling executor.sumbit() as below,

```
List<Stock> stockList ;

        executor.submit( ()-> {
            stockList = stockService.getAllStocks();
        });
```

I'm facing "Local variable stockList defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final" compiler error. I tried solve with help of Google but no luck :-(

Any help or suggestion appreciated, thanks!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I see the extraction but slightly different in my case.

Comment: You can't assign to a local variable from within a lambda expression.  Make the List an instance field and ensure you're not in a static context when you access it (unless it's qualified with a reference of course).

Comment: `List<Stock> stockList = executor.submit(() -> stockService.getAllStocks()) .get();`, but of course, this will destroy the benefit of asynchronous computation. You have to decide *when* to query the result via [`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get--). Before that, you *must not* try to use the result anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since stock service returns a list, why not just do the following:

```
    List<Stock> stockList = new ArrayList<>();

    executor.submit( ()-> {
        List<Stock> temp = stockService.getAllStocks());
        stockList.addAll(temp);
        //now that it's copied, submit to the executor.
        return temp;
    });
```

Since stockList is a reference, you are not changing the reference but only what stockList refers to. So you would not be violating the effectively final requirement.  Note:  Since the executor service returns immediately there may be a time delay before the list gets populated.

Comment: I tried with this approach as well, but returns empty list for some reason.

Comment: It was the executor service. It returns immediately before the list gets filled.  I waited to seconds and it filled it.  This is similar to what @Holger was talking about.  So I will edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: WJS - Yest that's true, it works, Thanks!

Comment: @WJS you’ve been lucky if waiting for a second gave you the desired result, but since waiting for an elapsed time does not establish a so called *happens-before* relationship between the `addAll` operation made in another thread and your subsequent use of the list, it is not thread-safe, regardless of how long you wait. There is no way around using the `Future` returned by `submit`, to detect the completion of the job correctly, establishing the necessary thread safety.